# ROS Melodic into Docker Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, ros

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 container and got error while adding ros melodic there.

> E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full

Neither ros-melodic nor ros-melodic-desktop.
Should I just get installed Ubuntu 18.04 as second OS next to Ubuntu 20.04 or set into VM?

Comment: try installing just `ROS-base` using `sudo apt install ros-melodic-ros-base` and see if that works.

Comment: Follow the steps from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu). I would recommend you to move to [ROS2](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/) if you haven't started your project yet, which have better capabilities.

Comment: Have you done `apt update`

Comment: @JayPatel oh, I haven't thought about ROS2, thanks for advice bro;)

Comment: @AlexeyR. mln times...

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to pull the ros-meldoic using those commands in my ubuntu 18.04

```
docker pull ros:melodic 

docker pull osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full // for GUI tool
```

To run something,

```
docker run -it --rm osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full roscore
```

Note: Melodic is not supported on Ubuntu Focal (20.04) and that's why docker is a good alternative